# Make HierachichalDataTemplate display children first. (Post-order (LRN))

Tags: wpf, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I want to display the path to my current element, like so:

```
Node1 > Node1_1 > Node1_1_1
```

The path is saved in a chain of Parent elements, for the example given above:

```
Node1_1_1.Parent == Node1_1
Node1_1.Parent == Node1
```

I thought the easiest way to archive this result is by using a `HierachichalDataTemplate` which first displays the children and then itself as `> Node.Name`. Starting from the `Node1_1_1` element.

The problem is the `HierachichalDataTemplate` displays the current `DataContext` first and then the children. I basically want to archive [post-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order_(LRN)) traversal of my `Parent`-tree.

Is there any way to archive that? I thought about redefining the template of the `HierachichalDataTemplate` somehow, but I don't know enough about WPF yet to archive this myself.

Comment: I think `HierachichalDataTemplate` can display other thing than the current `Datacontext` itself... how about displaying the _rootElement_ of your `DataContext` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure what you mean by "displaying the path" but I guess you want to be able to select an item in your treeview and shows its path in a seperate textbox control like in the Windows Explorer. If thats the case you need to keep track of the selected item and resolve its parent relationship up to the root whenever the selected item changed.

That is, every item in your viewmodel needs to implement a Parent interface like this (assuming every viewmodel item implements an IItem interface as shown here:
https://github.com/Dirkster99/InplaceEditBoxLib/blob/1a25512c7a5c4611809162d625ff9137a4ccb456/source/Solution/SolutionLib/Interfaces/IParent.cs)

```
public interface IParent
{
   IItem Parent { get; }
}
```

This interface enables you to accumulate a path by browsing towards a trees root using a while loop like this:

```
IItem node = MyTree.SelectedItem;
string path = MyTree.SelectedItem.Name; //Assuming you have a SelectedItem
while (node.Parent != null)
{
  path = path.Parent.Name + " > " + path;
}
```

Comment: While this technically solves the problem it doesn't have some of the nice properties redefining your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` has. Namely you have to add your own handling for changes in the tree-structure.